# arrow keys not working in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Ok this is too weird!

I have an input box within a fancybox, when I type something and want to move between characters and when I press the left or right arrow keys, it doesn't move...

The arrow keys just doesn't work!

anybody faced a similar issue before?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a known fancybox issue as fancybox is capturing those key presses for its own purposes.

You can see someone's solution posted here:
http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/b3c617631c465424?pli=1

They seem to add an option to the plug-in to allow disabling the FB specific arrow-key usage so you can have them behave normally when you like.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in Fancybox 1.3.2 (a few months after the question was asked): http://fancybox.net/changelog/

There are several other fixes; I highly recommend upgrading.